# Cache images to disk directly using retriveImage()?

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I'm using Kingfisher to download images in the following way:

```
 KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url!, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in
            if let image = image {
```

I was wondering if it is possible to cache them directly on the disk? Since I'm retrieving a lot of images, from time to time the memory can struggle a bit.

Answer (score 0):

On the [doc](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher#features) of Kingfisher there is already a method is available. Which will set the image from a url and at the same time it will handle the cache.

```
let url = URL(string: "url_of_your_image")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

[More info on CocoaDocs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Kingfisher/1.7.1/)

Comment: They way I'm doing it is just fine, since I do not assign my images to a imageView, but using them as overlays on Google Maps. I just need to know if I can store them on disk instead of, by default, in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://onevcat.github.io/Kingfisher/Classes/ImageCache.html#/s:vC10Kingfisher10ImageCache13maxMemoryCostSu) for `ImageCache` states that you can configure the amount of memory that Kingfisher will use via the `maxMemoryCost` property. It says the default is unlimited and apparently represents that with a 0.

I've not tried it, but you could try setting it to a very low number (since it refers to the total number of pixels, a number like 10 would ensure that basically no images are in memory) and see what happens.